# References for the moduli space of conformal structures on a disk minus boundary points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, teichmueller-theory

In an article I'm reading, it is said that the moduli space of conformal structures on a disk minus $k+1$ boundary points is a ($k-2$)-dimensional manifold. I want to understand why and have done some quick research, and it seems I need to look into notions related to Teichmüller theory; however, I know nothing about these things, and I don't know what to search for exactly. I've glanced at Farb & Margalit, "Primer on Mapping Class Groups", but all the compact surfaces they consider are punctured in their interior, not on the boundary.

I would be really grateful if someone had a proof (if this is an easy, well known fact), or a reference for this.

Comment: Could you give the precise definition of this moduli space? (There are two different spaces one might use here. For one of them the proof is fairly obvious, the other one- I am not sure the claim is true.)

Comment: @studiosus I admit I haven't thought long and hard about this before asking. The only thing that the author of the article adds is that this space is supposedly the "space of ordered ($k+1$)-tuples of points on the circle $S^1$ by the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(D^2).$" I suppose that the usual results about quotients by Lie groups show that this is a manifold of dimension $(k+1) - 3 = (k-2)$ since $\dim \operatorname{Aut}(D^2) = \dim \mathit{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) = 3.$ And I'm pretty sure the reason why this is the space we're looking at is because of the Riemann mapping theorem...

Comment: It should actually be $\mathit{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R}),$ but they're of the same dimension.

Comment: Then this is indeed true: You can fix the first three points. This gets rid of the conformal automorphisms. Now, your space is an open subset of $R^{k-2}$.